# Как получить доступ к переменной | y18n

Tags: json, node.js, i18n

Привет.
Вопрос 1.
Не могу получить переменную используя модуль y18n для node.
Подскажите как правильно? Какой сепаратор должен быть ("user.name")?
en.json

```
{"hello": "Hello", "user": {"name": "David"}}
```

app.js

```
let y18n = require("y18n");
let str = y18n.__("hello") + " " + y18n.__("user.name");
console.log(str)
```

console
Ожидания: Hello David
Реальность: Hello user.name

Вопрос 2.
Почему метод y18n.__ возвращает такую строку
en.json

```
{"house": {"flat": {"room": "kitchen"}}}
```

app.js

```
let y18n = require("y18n");
let house = y18n.__("house");
console.log(house); // {flat: {room: "kitchen"}}
console.log(typeof house); // string
console.log(JSON.parse(house)); // Error, Unexpected token h in JSON at position 2
```

Строка для парсинга должна бить {'flat': {'room': "kitchen"}}, а получается хоть что.
Конфиг опустил. Файл находит.

Comment: Задавайте всегда по одному вопросу.

Comment: Делать 2 отдельных вопроса на один метод, ну не оч...